# delete all reference to microsoft account under windows 11

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, windows-11

when i installed windows 11, i had to create a microsoft account. After the installation, I created a local account and deleted the microsoft account.

Now when I want to save a file in Micosoft Word, I get the proposal to save it in One Drive and I can see the email address I used during the installation of windows 11([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO2Lo.jpg)).

I already deleted the microsoft online account. I also uninstalled OneDrive.

How to delete all references (email) to the account that was used during the installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove OneDrive from Save As :

- Open Word
- Go to menu *File > Account* and ensure that you're not still signed in to
  the Microsoft Account
- Go to menu *File > Options > Save* and uncheck
  "Show additional places for saving even if sign-in may be required"
- Click OK
- Restart Word.